# local image take a long time to load when uri image are downloading - React Native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, image-loading

When I created my application, the images I placed worked perfectly and loaded normally.

Later, connect to the server and there are images that I have to display through url. As a large list, there are many images that must be downloaded causing all the images of the app (buttons, logos, etc) to enter a kind of thread, which causes this problem.

> Adding image code:

`<Image source={buttonAddToCart} style={styles.buttonIncrease} />`

and `buttonAddToCart` is a import.

`import buttonAddToCart from '../../assets/images/buttonAddToCart.png';`

the `styles.buttonIncrease`

```
buttonIncrease: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        marginTop: 35,
    },
```

> Example when load image by `uri`

```
<Image
    source={{ uri: category.image_url }}
    style={styles.categoryPicture}/>
```

Comment: can you add the code as to how are you loading the images?

Comment: @pritishvaidya code added

Comment: so are you getting any `errors` in the `console`,or does it gets fixed after **restarting** and also if it is working with `rendering small no of the images`?

Comment: No error in the console or any type. Just the images that are accessed as local paths take a lot of time when there are many images that are loading via url

Comment: just one more think,i would like to know if you are using any module bundler with it?

Comment: no, native `Image`

Comment: try once with `source={{uri: 'the-url'}}` or add the complete code :(

Comment: I do not need to access the image by `uri` because it is a local image, the other images that charge from other files that are remote if the charge with` uri`. Example added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a clear solution to this issue, I came across this `react-native-cached-image` library and it helped me a lot to camouflage this, although basically the problem remains